# Having problems while updation in asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

My create and delete operations are working well. But, the Edit function is giving the following error :- **Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.**

***NOTE:-*** `CatPicView` is a ViewModel merging the two entities `Category` and `Picture`

Following is the code for my Edit action code :-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CatPicView catPic)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(catPic.Picture.PictureUrl))
        {
            if (catPic.Category.PictureId == null)
            {
                Picture picture = new Picture();
                picture.PictureUrl = catPic.Picture.PictureUrl;
                db.Pictures.Add(picture);
                catPic.Category.PictureId = picture.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Entry(catPic.Picture).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        db.Entry(catPic.Category).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.ParentCategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name", catPic.Category.ParentCategoryId);
    return View(catPic);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the debuger, check the properties of the object you are trying to update. The most likely is that you have an ID in null.

To fix this, you should place a hidden field holding the id of the modified object so when posting the form it became mapped to your object.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ID that does not exist in the current context which is picture.Id. At the time that you are using it an ID has not yet been generated, add db.SaveChanges before attempting to use the ID.

```
if (catPic.Category.PictureId == null)
{
    Picture picture = new Picture();
    picture.PictureUrl = catPic.Picture.PictureUrl;
    db.Pictures.Add(picture);
    db.SaveChanges();
    catPic.Category.PictureId = picture.Id;
}
```